# Is the graph acyclic?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, graph-theory

A [Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) is a type of graph that has no cycles in it. In other words, if there is a link from node A to node B, there exists no path from B to A (via any nodes).

## Challenge

Determine whether the directed graph given as input is acyclic.

## Input

A list of lists of integers representing the links between nodes, where a node is identified by its index in the list.

## Output

Standard I/O for decision problems; generally a truthy value for acyclic graphs, and a falsy one for cyclic graphs. Additionally, your program may halt/not halt to indicate truthy and falsy, if you wish.

## Test Cases

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5], [], [6], [6], []]
```

Represents the following graph (where all edges are directed downwards):

```
        0
      /   \
     1     2
    / \   /
   3  4  5
      | /
      6
```

This example is acyclic, so the result should be truthy.

```
[[1, 3], [2], [0], [1]]
```

Represents the following graph:

```
 -----<-----<----
/                \
0 --> 3 --> 1 --> 2
 \---->----/
```

This example is cyclic, so the result should be falsey. (Sorry for my terrible drawing; if this is unclear let me know.)

## Constraints

- No input will ever be invalid; i.e. no node will link to a node that does not exist
- Self loops *must* be handled (`[[0]]` is a cyclic graph)

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the fewest bytes in each language wins.

Comment: [Very closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/107274/45941). It could potentially be considered a duplicate, because checking if cycles exist is a core part of that challenge.

Comment: Is one-indexing acceptable? May we output truthy for cyclic and falsey for acyclic?

Comment: Feel free to use [this drawing](https://hastebin.com/folanufola) or modify it to suit you.

Comment: @Mego I did see that one before posting, but I think this is a much easier challenge

Comment: @JonathanAllan One-indexing is fine. And yes, based on [standard I/O for decision problems](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12308/69054) you may use false for true and true for false.

Answer (score 8):

## Mathematica, <s>80</s> <s>44</s> <s>40</s> <s>30</s> 22 bytes

```
#//.x_:>#[[Union@@x]]&
```

Uses 1-based indexing for input. Returns an empty list iff the graph is acyclic.

#### Example:

```
In[1]:= #//.x_:>#[[Union@@x]]&[{{2,3},{4,5},{6},{},{7},{7},{}}]

Out[1]= {}

In[2]:= #//.x_:>#[[Union@@x]]&[{{2,4},{3},{1},{2}}]

Out[2]= {{2, 4}, {3}, {1}, {2}}

In[3]:= #//.x_:>#[[Union@@x]]&[{{1}}]

Out[3]= {{1}}
```

Comment: Nice job dealing with the strict input format (and I didn't know about `LoopFreeGraphQ`!). Too bad`FindCycle@#=={}` doesn't save anything over `AcyclicGraphQ@#`.

Comment: Can you replace `#2[[1]]` by `#&@@#2`?

Comment: Could you add an explanation? Also, is the `+1` just to correct for `0`-indexing? If so, it could be eliminated.

Comment: Is there a perhaps short way to convert to adjacency matrix, raise it to a high power, and check if the result is zero?

Comment: @xnor The graph is acyclic if and only if the only eigenvalue of its adjacency matrix is 0. But I can't find any short way. `f@g_:={0}==Union@Eigenvalues[SparseArray[#+1->1&/@#,Length@g]&/@g]` is 66 chars.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>8</s>  7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
µị³FµL¡
```

A full program, printing no output for an acyclic input; or some output for a cyclic input.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@39o68Pd3Yc2ux3a6nNo4f///6OjjXQUTGJ1FKKNQYQhiDCKjQUA)**

#### How?

```
µị³FµL¡ - Main link: list of lists of natural numbers, g
µ   µ ¡ - repeat
     L  - length times:
  ³     -   program's 3rd command line argument, 1st program input, g
 ị      -   index into
   F    -   flatten (makes a list of nodes that are reachable, possibly with repeats)
        - implicit print - If cyclic:  it contains integers, and the Jelly representation
                                       is a `[]` enclosed `, ` separated string of them.
                           If acyclic: it contains nothing, anf the Jelly representation
                                       is an empty string (the `[]` is not even printed)
```

Comment: The result should be falsy for cyclic instances.

Comment: I asked about it and got [this response](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/122344/is-the-graph-acyclic/122398?noredirect=1#comment300399_122344).

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes

```python
f=lambda G,s=0,v=-1:G[s:]and all(f(G,s+1,x)for x in(G+[sum(G,[])])[v])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#RY/BCoMwDIbP8ylytJiBbbcdhJ59iJCDQwKCuqGd@PYuVeag@UOa8CX/JqFvhmfbQI1zKHEJV1vVNFfcjC00fZ9Lrp3C4mrkNcEK3ZjXBc2fQf@JDRta2GzRQgAii@AYgTzCLeV7khSPU5iz6PZhRipT5f@VBtpD0f0yep3K5NzgE2ZfUyax2pWDmHBy4o6nd6Qz6ICohVotAEWL0WH0KBbFoXiusst76sYI6ths2Rc)

An n-vertex graph is cyclic only if one can take an n-step path. In an acyclic graph, no vertex on the path can repeat so it must hit a dead end.

This recursive function tries all paths in the graph `G`, tracking the current number of steps `s` and current vertex `v`. Once `s` is at least `len(G)`, we the Falsey value of `[]` is returned. To allow the walk to start on any vertex, the initial phantom vertex `v=-1` connects to every (reachable) node of `G`, extracted as `sum(G,[])`.

An iterative version tied in length.

**[Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 70 bytes**

```python
G=input()
r=sum(G,[])
for _ in G:r=sum([G[v]for v in r],[])
print[]==r
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@@9um5lXUFqioclVZFtcmqvhrhMdq8mVll@kEK@QmafgbgURjnaPLosFiZaBRItiwaoKijLzSqJjbW2L/v@PjjbUUTCK1VGINtZRMAHRpiAChM3gRGwsAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 28 bytes (halts or doesn’t halt)

```hs
f g|let s=(>>=s.(g!!))=g>>=s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYe9CoAgAAZf5cvJQIJ@N3uCtkYRFDKLLCpt690Nl4a74xbtN@NcjDPs60yA57TvuS@ozbI85zZN3PV6gGOGECVDJRlEzdCktkmJ7peUUN5cCucTxnAPB8iiXTATiR8)

For any list `xs` of nodes, `s xs` = `xs >>= s . (g !!)` = `[y | x <- xs, y <- s (g !! x)]` does a recursive search through all nodes reachable from them.  We run this on all nodes in the graph with `g >>= s`.

## Haskell, 36 bytes (returns `True` or `False`)

```hs
f g=null$foldr(=<<)(id=<<g)$(g!!)<$g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P00h3TavNCdHJS0/J6VIw9bGRlMjMwVIpWuqpNvZRWukKypqxv7PTczMU7BVSMnnUlAoKMrMK1HQSFOIjjbUUTCK1VGINtZRMAHRpiAChM3gRGysJoYeY5AEWKMBiDAEqvkPAA)

For any list `xs` of nodes, `(g!!) =<< xs` = `[y | x <- xs, y <- g !! x]` is the list of endpoints of all edges starting at nodes in `xs`.  Now if `g` has length *n*, then

`foldr(=<<)(id=<<g)$(g!!)<$g`
= `foldr (=<<) (id =<< g) [(g!!), (g!!), …, (g!!), (g!!)]` (*n* repetitions)
= `(g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< … =<< (g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< id =<< g`
= `(g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< … =<< (g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< concat g`
= `(g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< … =<< (g!!) =<< (g!!) =<<` [endpoints of all edges, i.e., paths of length 1]
= `(g!!) =<< (g!!) =<< … =<< (g!!) =<<` [endpoints of all paths of length 2]
= …
= `(g!!) =<<` [endpoints of all paths of length *n*]
= [endpoints of all paths of length *n* + 1],

which is `null` if and only if the graph is acyclic.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 20 bytes

```apl
⍳∘≢∨.∊⊂{⍵∪∊⍺[⍵]}⍣≡¨⊢
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob2pm/qO2CQb/04Dko97NjzpmPOpc9Khjhd6jjq5HXU3Vj3q3PupYBeL07ooGcmJrH/UuftS58NCKR12L/v9P0zBUMNLUMFYw0dTQMdV81LtGQ8dME4SBTC6QrDGQB1ShYwDEhpoA)

Answer (score 1):

### Mathematica, 82 bytes

```
AcyclicGraphQ[g=Graph[Join@@Thread/@Thread[Range@Length@#->#]]]&&LoopFreeGraphQ@g&
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda i:map(f,l[i]);l=input();map(f,range(len(l)))
```

Crashes if and only if the graph is cyclic, due to infinite recursion. Takes input via stdin.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@59mm5OYm5SSqJBplZtYoJGmkxOdGatpnWObmVdQWqKhaQ0RLUrMS0/VyEnN08jR1NT8/z86OlYn2iA2FgA)

Comment: This doesn't work for `[[], [2], [1]]` (aside from the dubious interpretation of I/O rules).

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was missing something. This should work now, though it is significantly longer.

Comment: I think this still doesn't work, like for `[[],[0]]`.

Comment: You are correct. I was trying to over-zealously golf my fix, which caused that issue. Now it really should work, for real :)

Comment: I don't like infinite recursion as an output method. In particular, this will also crash on a sufficiently large acyclic graph.

Comment: My original intent was for it to halt if and only if the graph were acyclic, which would occur if the runtime stack were infinitely large.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 98 bytes

```
f=(a,b=[...a.keys()],c=b.filter(i=>b.some(b=>a[b].some(b=>b==i))))=>1/b[c.length]?f(a,c):!(1/c[0])
```

Returns `true` for acyclic, `false` for cyclic. Explanation: Starting with the set `b` of all the nodes in `a`, the subset of all nodes of `b` which are the target of a link is iterated until it doesn't change. If the resulting subset is empty then the graph is acyclic.